# how to retrieve facebook, twitter, and google profile images without error using paperclip in rails 3.2

Tags: authentication, paperclip, omniauth

i have setup devise to handle my authentication and am also using omniauth to do the third party authentication which also works well for me.
i can retrieve the name, nickname, by setting this method in my user model

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_create do |user|
      user.provider = auth.provider
      user.uid = auth.uid
      user.username = auth.info.nickname
      user.username = auth.info.first_name
      user.email = auth.info.email
      user.photo = auth.info.image

    end
  end
```

and i use paperclip to handle my image processing 
whenever i try to authenticate a user with

user.photo = auth.info.image

i get an error like this

```
Paperclip::AdapterRegistry::NoHandlerError in OmniauthCallbacksController#facebook

No handler found for "http://graph.facebook.com/100006033401739/picture?type=square"
```

anyway around this or is there something am not doing right?

my OmniauthCallbacksController controller is as thus:

```
class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def all
    user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
    if user.persisted?
      flash.notice = "Signed in!"
      sign_in_and_redirect user
    else
      session["devise.user_attributes"] = user.attributes
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end
  alias_method :twitter, :all
  alias_method :facebook, :all
  alias_method :google_oauth2, :all
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that paperclip requires an image **file** and you are just passing an image **url**.

I'd suggest having 2 different attributes: `photo` and `remote_photo`:

- If logging in with facebook, google and twitter, you would set the `remote_photo` attribute to the `auth.info.image` returned.
- If uploading a photo, you would use the `photo` attribute.

However, if you want to download a person's facebook, google and twitter picture anyway, you can do this:

```
user.photo = URI.parse(auth.info.image) if auth.info.image?
```

This feature is kinda new so be sure that the version of Paperclip you are using is > 3.1.3.

Comment: thanks i have no error anymore. and my paperclip version is 3.5.1 how do i display the image, cos it shows a broken image after validation and i now store the images in amazon s3.

Comment: I get the following error: `Paperclip::AdapterRegistry::NoHandlerError in Users::OmniauthCallbacksController#facebook
No handler found for #<URI::HTTP http://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/103233960499999/picture>` 
you can help? I have version 5.2.1 of paperclip.

Answer (score 1):

From Paperclip version `5.2`, the gem no longer loads **IO adapters** by default. It means if you pass an URI/HTTP strings/etc. as an attachment, it won't upload it automatically, as it used to do.

If you need to do that - for example, upload an photo that comes from Facebook Graph (omniauth integration) - add one or more adapters to your `config/initializers/paperclip.rb`, for example:

```
Paperclip::HttpUrlProxyAdapter.register
```

See other adapters here: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#io-adapters.